# Check whether $p(x,y) = xye^{-x-y}$ is a joint density function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to check whether...

$$p(x,y) = xye^{-x-y}$$

...is a joint density function outside the region $R$ where $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$

First I wrote the integral...

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xye^{-x-y}dxdy$$
...separate....
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ye^{-y}dxdy$$

...integration by parts for $x$...

$$-xe^{-x}\int e^{-x}dx$$

...same process goes for $y$...

$$[-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}]_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdot [-ye^{-y}-e^{-y}]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$

Now I am lost. I try to plug in the infinities but I am not sure how to tell if it is a joint density function. The answer I get is infinity but I think that may be wrong.

$$[(Indeterminate - 0)-(\infty + \infty)] \cdot [(Indeterminate - 0)-(\infty + \infty)]$$

$$=\infty$$

Comment: This is very easy if you are willing to use the fact that f(x)g(y) is a joint density function whenever f and g  are density functions. If X and Y are independent random variables with densities f and g then f(x)g(y) is the joint density of (X,Y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We already know that the value of the double integral restricted to non-negative $x$ and $y$ is $1$, and the function is only non-negative for $xy\ge0$, so the only additional domain you can add would require that both $x$ and $y$ are negative. In that case the double integral would exceed the value of $1$. There is nothing wrong with this, but one would have to divide the original function by the new value so it would not be the same function.

So no, it will not be a probability density function unless it is defined only for non-negative $x$ and $y$.